# Problem writing on a .txt file using user input

Tags: java, text-files, nio

I am writing a program that takes user input and displays it in a text file. I am having trouble having the input save on the file. Other similar questions have suggested to close the BufferedWriter, however I'm using a try-with-resource block which, as I understand it, should auto-close the resource. When I use fileWriter.close(); the text is saved however because it is being closed it will not be re-opened and I am given an IOException due to the stream being closed. How could I fix this issue?

Main Method

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("/Users/Coding/Desktop/myFile.txt").toAbsolutePath();
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             BufferedWriter fileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

            Reader reader = new Reader(scan, path, fileWriter);
            reader.menu();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Reader Class

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reader {

    Path path;
    Scanner scan;
    BufferedWriter fileWriter;

    Reader(Scanner scan, Path path, BufferedWriter fileWriter) {

        this.scan = scan;
        this.path = path;
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
    }

    public void menu() throws IOException {
        String task;

        do{
            System.out.print("What would you like to do today?: ");
            task = scan.nextLine();
            switch(task){
                case "1":
                    addData();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                menu();
            }
        }while(!task.equals("6"));

    }

    void addData() throws IOException {
        boolean cont = false;
        do try {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Player: ");
            String playerName = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Games Played: ");
            int gamesPlayed = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Goals Made: ");
            int goals = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Assists Made: ");
            int assists = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Points Scored: ");
            int points = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Saves Made: ");
            int saves = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Shots Made: ");
            int shotsOnGoal = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            fileWriter.write(
                    playerName + " " + gamesPlayed + " " + goals + " " +
                            assists + " " + points + " " + saves + " " + shotsOnGoal);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Enter Valid Input");
            cont = true;
//insert finally clause to close fileWriter here
        }while(cont);

    }
}
```

**IF** fileWriter is closed in a finally clause after catching the NumberFormatException as indicated in the comment of the code, the following Exception is displayed

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:107)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:224)
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
    at Reader.addData(Reader.java:74)
    at Reader.menu(Reader.java:28)
    at TextReader.main(TextReader.java:16)
```

Comment: Add the stack trace from the exception. Also note that you never re-set `cont` to false if any input ever was wrong (i.e. it will stay an infinite loop asking the user to enter more and more players).

Comment: exception has been added, see update. Note line numbers may vary from code shown here as some irrelevant code was cut out to stay on point of the issue

Comment: So the code you posted here doesn't actually cause the exception, since you've left out the `finally` block. Why not post the code that **does**? Also: it seems that `addData` is the wrong place to close the `FileWriter`. If anything you'd want to close it in the `main` (it's easiest if you always close resources in the same method that opens them) or maybe in `menu` after you're done writing (i.e. when the user chooses to quit).

Comment: You're closing the stream within the loop so if the loop runs again, you're trying to write to a closed stream. You should not pass a stream from one method to another and then close it. Instead open the stream using ```try with resources``` where you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("/Users/Coding/Desktop/myFile.txt").toAbsolutePath();
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             BufferedWriter fileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

            Reader reader = new Reader(scan, path, fileWriter);
            reader.menu();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Reader Class

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reader {

    Path path;
    Scanner scan;
    BufferedWriter fileWriter;


    Reader(Scanner scan, Path path, BufferedWriter fileWriter) {

        this.scan = scan;
        this.path = path;
        this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
    }

    public void menu() throws IOException {
        String task;

        do{
            System.out.print("What would you like to do today?: ");
            task = scan.nextLine();
            switch(task){
                case "1":
                    addData();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                
            }
            fileWriter.close();
        }while(!task.equals("6"));

    }

    void addData() throws IOException {
        boolean cont = false;
        do try {
            System.out.print("Enter Name of Player: ");
            String playerName = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Games Played: ");
            int gamesPlayed = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Goals Made: ");
            int goals = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Assists Made: ");
            int assists = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Points Scored: ");
            int points = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Saves Made: ");
            int saves = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Shots Made: ");
            int shotsOnGoal = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            fileWriter.write(
                    playerName + " " + gamesPlayed + " " + goals + " " +
                            assists + " " + points + " " + saves + " " + shotsOnGoal);
            cont = false;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Enter Valid Input");
            cont = true;
        }while(cont);

    }
}
```

Comment: yes i was told i should if in a situation like this, i would click accept answer but it requires me to wait 2 days.

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer that explains what the code does and how it solves the problem.